# How select all data using HAVING clause in WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

I have created a table which is keeps records of which product is sold by whom and how much each month;

| month | total | product | cons_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 10 | xyz | 123 |
| 2020-02 | 5 | abc | 456 |
| 2020-02 | 4 | def | 789 |

I was creating a query from this table to find out who has sold over 500 products on certain products since the beginning of the year, but I was a bit confused at the time of writing. Because i am not needed to query how much it sells during the year, but how much it sells each month that's i need to find. I can easily find more than 500 sales in total during a year with this query:

```
SELECT cons_name, product, SUM(total)
FROM TMP_REPORT
WHERE product IN ('abc','xyz')
GROUP BY cons_name, product
HAVING sum(total) > 500
```

But when it came to querying in detail I got this far:

```
SELECT 
  month,
  product,
  cons_name,
  total
FROM TMP_REPORT 
WHERE product IN ('abc','xyz')
AND cons_name IN 
              (SELECT 
                 cons_name
               FROM TMP_REPORT 
               WHERE 
                 product IN ('abc','xyz') 
               GROUP BY 
                 cons_name 
               HAVING sum(total) > 500)
```

The result of this query showed even the totals of sold product are not 500. For example, we would expect the cons_name named '123' to not be in the query result for only 200 sold 'abc' products in a year, but it does exist because of where clause. I knew my mistakes but I don't know that how to fix.

How can i do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses `SUM` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(total) OVER (PARTITION BY cons_name, product) sum_total
    FROM TMP_REPORT t
    WHERE product IN ('abc', 'xyz')
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE sum_total > 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't clearly understand you requirement, I assume you need a query to fetch the product that sold more than 500 unit on monthly basis. I hope below query will fetch the records you need.

```
-- YearlyReportCTE will Qualify the people who sold more than 500 units in total (i.e. yearly from your statement)
WITH YearlyReportCTE AS (

SELECT  
  product,
  cons_name,
  SUM(total) AS Total
FROM #TMP_REPORT
WHERE product in ('abc','xyz')
GROUP BY product,cons_name
HAVING SUM(total) > 500
)--This Query will fetch the month wise report from the qulified records
SELECT  month,
  TR.product,
  TR.cons_name,
  SUM(TR.total) AS Total
FROM #TMP_REPORT TR
JOIN YearlyReportCTE YR ON YR.cons_name = TR.cons_name
AND YR.product = TR.product
GROUP BY month,TR.product,TR.cons_name
```

Comment: It is a little complex. I have already find the total number of sales monthly as you have written, what I need is to find the monthly sales numbers of people who have sold product more than 500 sales in a year.